# Swift method which returns array

Tags: ios, swift

So, I have a question about how my class and struct interfaces should look like in Swift.
For example I have a class or struct which has method:

```
func getAllObjectsFromSomewhere() -> [Int]
```

but, imagine that this method not always return you some array of Int, so there are few different ways how to handle it.

- `func getAllObjectsFromSomewhere() -> [Int]?`
- `func getAllObjectsFromSomewhere() throws -> [Int]`  Throws custom ErrorType with types like: NotFound or EmptyArray
- `func getAllObjectsFromSomewhere() -> [Int] { /* some code and then just return an empty Int array */ return [Int]() }`

So, my question is, when and why I should take which approach of organising the interface? Does it make much difference? Is there any guidelines?

Comment: Do you have a specific use case or more details about this method? Or is this purely hypothetical?

Comment: @RyanPoolos I faced this during building architecture for one of my apps, but I think I want the most common answer, so yes, this is purely hypothetical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three approaches are valid, depending on a situation:

- When getting objects may or may not be possible, and impossibility does not necessarily mean an error, use `[Int]?`. This lets you differentiate between an empty array and no array at all.
- When getting objects must always be possible, and impossibility to get them means you have an error, use `throws`
- When inability to get objects should always be treated as an absence of objects, use `[Int]` and an empty array.

Comment: That is what was in my mind, but, I am not quite sure about application.
For example, I am trying to get a list of objects from some abstract database. Which one I should use? Does it depends on which level of architecture I want to get this?

Comment: Because, for example, if it is low level model, I want to deal with throws, if it is something close to view, like viewModel, I don't want to deal even with nil values.

Comment: And one more time for example, if I executed request to database, and I got  0 results, should I return empty array? or nil?

Comment: @PavelGatilov When DB request returns successfully with zero rows, this means that there are no rows, but they *could be there*. Hence, you should return an empty array. Returning `nil` or throwing an exception should be an option only when there is an error with the request. You should always throw if the request itself is invalid due to a programming error.

Answer (score 1):

This is just my opinion and I don't have any guidelines or anything to throw behind it, but...

Straight out of the box I think this is a perfect case for optionals, meaning this signature:

```
func getAllObjectsFromSomewhere() -> [Int]?
```

But (as always :)) it depends on the situation. Here are my thoughts on your scenarios.

#### func getAllObjectsFromSomewhere() -> [Int]?

This is what I'd normally use if I was to implement that function.

You have a normal case where you expect to get some `Int`s returned in an array.

If for some reason there are no elements, then you get a `nil` in return which you can then check for using a `guard` or an `if let`.

Normally, an empty array should't be enough reason to actually start throwing exceptions, but it depends on the specific case of course.

#### func getAllObjectsFromSomewhere() throws -> [Int]

If however, you actually expect that your `getAllObjectsFromSomewhere` **must** return a value, then it would make sense to throw an error if for some reason there wasn't any content to return.

#### func getAllObjectsFromSomewhere() -> [Int]

This is the solution I like the least.

When you call your `getAllObjectsFromSomewhere` you still need to do a check and see if the returned array actually contains anything (`if getAllObjectsFromSomewhere().count > 0`) before you decide what to do....why not use `guard` or `if let` for that?

As said, this was just my thoughts on the three scenarios, hope you can use them.